# Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile and run my java program in openshift via a `DIY` java application. I have managed to compile my `*.java` files and it outputs my `*.class` with no error but when I try to run my main class I get an error that says

> Error: Could not find or load main class

This is my Listener.java code

```
package matchfaces;

import Luxand.FSDK;

public class Listener {

     public static final String JAVABRIDGE_PORT = "5699";
     static final php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner runner =
     php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner.getInstance(JAVABRIDGE_PORT);
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.lang.InterruptedException
     */
    public static void main(  String[] args  ) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
              System.loadLibrary("facesdk");
             int res = FSDK.ActivateLibrary("XXXX");
             FSDK.Initialize();
             FSDK.SetFaceDetectionParameters(true, true, 384);
             FSDK.SetFaceDetectionThreshold(5);

             if (res == FSDK.FSDKE_OK) {
                    System.out.printf("FaceSDK activated", "FaceSDK activated\n");
            } else {
                     System.out.printf("Error activating FaceSDK: ", res + "\n");
            }
    } catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
             System.out.printf("exception ", e.getMessage());
    }
    try{
    runner.waitFor();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.printf("Error: ", ex.getMessage() + "\n");
    }
    // System.exit(0);
}

}
```

There is nothing wrong with the main class above, as when I run it with netbeans it compiles and runs correctly.

But when I try to do the same with shell script in openshift, then it doesn't work.
 My start shell script is as follows:

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR

export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

libs="libs"

export LIB=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR$libs

src="src"

export JAVA_FILES=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR$src

export MATCHFACES=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR$src/matchfaces

export JARPATH=$(JARS=("$LIB"/*.jar); IFS=:; echo "${JARS[*]}")

cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR

if [[ -z "$OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP" ]]; then export OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP="$OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP"; fi

if [[ -z "$OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT" ]]; then export OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT="$OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT"; fi

javac -classpath $JARPATH $MATCHFACES/*.java > ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR}/compile.log 2>&1 &

cd ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/src/matchfaces

dir > ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR}/output1.log 2>&1 &

${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR} > ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR}/output2.log 2>&1 &

java Listener > ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR}/Listener.log 2>&1 &
```

What could I be doing wrong? And Please not the main method argument was not the issue it was there previously, but I removed it because the argument parameter is not compulsory.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the String[] args in the main class parameters. That's probably it.

Comment: it usually doesn't matter. Same result.

Comment: `it usually doesn't matter`. It actually matters.